# $router redefine and Vue.use(Vuex) should be called only once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

My project created by [webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) template!!;

**npm run build**

online it can work well, but the vendor.js is too big!

modified webpack config `webpack.prod.conf.js` add this:

js

```
externals: {
  'vue': 'Vue',
  'vee-router': 'VueRouter',
  'vuex': 'Vuex',
},
```

i separated the `vue`,`vue-router`,`vuex` , include by CDN  ! like:

html

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.3.1/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.3.1"></script>
</body>
```

but when i upload the file to line, some problems like:

> vuex@2.3.1:667 [vuex] already installed. Vue.use(Vuex) should be
>   called only once.
>   vendor.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router
>       at Function.defineProperty ()
>       at Function.v [as install] (vendor.js:24)
>       at Function.Vue.use (vue.js:4110)
>       at Object. (vendor.js:24)
>       at r (manifest.js:1)
>       at Object. (app.js:1)
>       at r (manifest.js:1)
>       at Object. (app.js:1)
>       at r (manifest.js:1)
>       at Object. (app.js:1)

can someone help me?

Comment: Adding the script from another source doesn't really affect the downloaded size very much. You're just downloading the source from a different place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load Vue & Vuex via CDN - you do not need to use Vue.use (...)

Comment: Yes,I did!! Just changed to CDN